# Transparent Navbar not activating on load

Tags: jquery, css, navbar

I'm trying to have my navbar at the top of the page be transparent until the user starts scrolling, but when the page loads, the unstyled gray is present. The transparent nature doesn't activate until the user scrolls back up. What do I need to do to have the navbar be transparent when you first load the page?

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AE</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About Me</a>
                        <a href="#">My Life Before Code</a>
                        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container-full-big">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Hi. I'm Ashley.</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## CSS

```
.container-fluid {
    height: 60px;
}

.navbar-default {
    border: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.jumbotron {
    background: url("img/sunset.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
}
```

## JS

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $(".navbar-default").css("background", "#443e41");
        } else {
            $(".navbar-default").css("background", "transparent");
        }
    });
```

Comment: under/above your JS code write : 

$(".navbar-default").css("background", "transparent");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the `transparent` code part on `$(document).ready()` also

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar-default").css("background", "transparent");
});
```

You can try `$('window').load()` also:-

```
$('window').load(function(){
  $(".navbar-default").css("background", "transparent");
});
```

Comment: The $(document).ready() did the trick. Using the load function just maintained the unstyled gray, despite the scroll.. Thanks!

Comment: @AshleyEdds  glad to help you :):)